# plsql trigger on updating values

Tags: plsql

I need to create a trigger to prevent updating salary from persons table if the person is found in the studio table and the new salary<25000.
Those are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE persons
(id_person NUMBER (15),
name VARCHAR2 (20),
address VARCHAR2 (20),
sex CHAR (1),
birthdate DATE,
salary NUMBER (10));

CREATE TABLE studio
(name VARCHAR2 (20),
address VARCHAR2 (20),
id_president NUMBER (15));
```

This is the trigger but it doesn't work:

```
create or replace trigger president_salary  
before update on person  
begin  
if (new.id_person in ( select id_person from person join studio on (id_person=id.president) where id_person=new.id_person) AND new.salary<25000) then
dbms_outupt.putline('value to small');
end if;
end;
```

Comment: It would be helpful to people wanting to answer if you described **how** this doesn't work, so what happens with the trigger as you have it now compared to what you want to happen? It sounds like you might want to look into [`INSTEAD OF` triggers](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/triggers.htm#LNPLS20041).

Comment: @3N1GM4: `INSTEAD OF` triggers are only for views.

Comment: @LukeWoodward good point, I'll slowly back away now... :)

Comment: This won't be the only issue, but you are missing the colon in from of new. The default before and after column aliases are `:new` and `:old`.

Comment: you also need to `RAISE` an error for the trigger to prevent the update happening

Answer (score 0):

try a trigger more like

```
create or replace trigger president_salary  
before update on person  
begin  
    if (:new.id_person in ( select id_person from person join studio on (id_person=id.president) where id_person=:new.id_person) AND :new.salary<25000) then
    dbms_outupt.putline('value to small');
    RAISE NO_DATA_FOUND; --or some other exception
end if;
end;
```

note the correct use of `:new` and a `RAISE` statement  to cause the update to fail